# accessing properties in @RelationshipEntiry in Spring data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using spring data for Neo4j.
Initial design of the model looks like below:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends Neo4JBaseNode {
    @RelatedToVia(type = "HAS_DEVICE", elementClass = UserDevice.class, direction =       Direction.OUTGOING)  
    private List<Device> devices;
    .... ommited setters,getters
}



@NodeEntity
public class Device extends Neo4JBaseNode {
    private String type;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private String os;
    .... ommited setters,getters
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_DEVICE")
public class UserDevice {
   @StartNode
   private User user;
   @EndNode
   private Device device;
   private String deviceToken;
}
```

I need to have "deviceToken" when User is retrieve from database but I don't know how can I achieve that.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use @RelatedToVia to inject UserDevices rather than Devices, make sure you @Fetch it (if required), and then you'll have access to relation properties, as well as the entity properties. I.e. typically you'd either use

```
@RelatedTo
Set<Device> ... (if you don't care about the relationship properties)
```

OR

```
@RelatedToVia
Set<UserDevice> ... (if you care about the relationship as well as the end nodes)
```